# how to apply scheduled refresh with Web Anonymous Method in POWERBI?

Tags: power-bi-report-server

I already mentioned timeout limit which is 30 min in advanced editor as shown below but still it is showing an error I tried a lot but I failed to resolve this issue can anybody help me regarding this issue I made a connection with Web in PowerBI to get json file from URL with Anonymous Authentication method my gateway and server(URL) both are working properly but still showing an error when I apply scheduled refresh on PowerBI server.
[image]

[image]